# Array in function to replace with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I have hardcoded array called `users` in a PHP function:

```
protected static $users = array(
  'us1' => array('password'=>"pass1", 'fullname'=>"name1", 'email'=>"name1@mail.com"),
  'us2' => array('password'=>"pass2", 'fullname'=>"name2", 'email'=>"name2@mail.com"),
  'us3' => array('password'=>"pass3", 'fullname'=>"name3", 'email'=>"name3@mail.com"),
);
```

I need to connect this part of function to my `users` table in MySql so I dont have to type new users here in function.

I tried the following, but it gives me an error:

```
$sql = mysql_query('select username, password, fullname, email FROM s_users');
$users = array()

while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $users[] = $row_user;
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Do you want to add users stored in your MySQL databases to the `$users` array?

Comment: Ok. You go ahead and do that. Come back if you have a question!

Comment: Yes, I need this part of function to connect to my DB and read users stored in DB. So I can add users to MySQL and not to this function.

Comment: @marcom: Did you even *try* to implement it yourself?

Comment: Yes, but not successfully  ....

Comment: @marcom: In that case you should post the code you already have.

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with that code. what's the error? what's the expected and the actual result? are you connected to your db? does the query run successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $users[$row_user['username']] = $row_user;
}
```

And make sure to first check that `$sql` is valid (`if (!$sql) { // error processing }`), and that you print out the error if `$sql` is invalid (using `mysql_error`).

Comment: good catch! the original array had string keys